# How is drainage divide defined upstream of bifurcation?

Tags: hydrology, geography, mapping, hydrogeology

Recently, I visited the [Divide Creek birfucation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_Creek) in Canada where a creek bifurcates with one arm flowing to Pacific and the other to Arctic Ocean and I was wondering how does this rather rare situation plays with the concept of drainage divide.

[Per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drainage_divide), drainage divide is the boundary between two drainage basins. However, it cannot be practically determined what arm of the bifurcation the water flowing into it will continue. Hence the whole drainage basin of the creek upstream of the bifurcation cannot be said to belong to either the Pacific or the Arctic basins and it forms kind of a gap in the Continental Divide.

Drainage divides are often used to trace borders of political, economical, or other importance. Is there any convention for how a divide is traced in such situations?

What are all the various ways this has been dealt with? For instance, the Continental Divide and hence Alberta/British Columbia border seem to be traced along the western border of the non-defined area effectively granting it to Alberta.

Are there any historical stories where these non-defined parts of drainage divides led to disputes about how the border should be traced?